# Is it possible to include double curly braces inside an HTML attribute using Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's say I want to have `<input value='{{default}}'></input>` in regular HTML. The textbox with `{{default}}` as a default input will be displayed.

However I'm trying to do such thing with Vue but, won't work as expected

```
<md-input value='{{document_url}}'></md-input>
```

The error I'm getting is

```
in ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-c9c99006","hasScoped":false,"preserveWhitespace":false,"buble":{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0&bustCache!./components/template-heuristic-cases.vue
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `v-bind` instead of just using html `value` property:

```
<input :value="'{{default}}'">
```

This will output:

`{{default}}` in the browser.

---

For further case, if you want to bind the data option in the `value` then just concatenate them:

```
<input :value="'{{'+mydata+'}}'">

// ... inside data option:
mydata: 'my default'
```

Comment: for an input it should be v-model, not v-bind, right?

Comment: OP doesn't want to watch the data option. But just want to output the value.

Comment: technically you are right but it's very hard to imagine that there's a text box on the screen and its value will never be used. Y, THO?

Answer (score 0):

Had similar situation and simply accomplished with:

```
<input :value="document_url">
```

if outside of HTML element, use version with double curly braces:

```
<span>{{document_url}}</span>
```